# Temporary toilet installation

Tags: toilet, construction

I need to install a toilet in a my house while it is being built. The floor isn't ready yet and won't be for at least a couple of months and right know it is a rough concrete slab.

Since the soil pipe goes down from the toilet I cannot cut the pipe to size now as it will be too short after the floor is done.

I thought about making a base about 10 cm tall using brick and mortar and install the toilet on top of it (later I can remove the toilet and break the base). Does that work? Should I put plywood over the brick to keep the toilet more level?

Comment: I'd just box around the drain pipe with some 2x laid flat.  Make sure it's wide enough to support the commode.

Comment: Why can't you use a [portable toilet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_toilet)? They make small "travel" sized ones, that can be found at any camping store.

Comment: There are small conteiners for construction sites with bathrooms, but I'm in a stage that I want to move everything construction related to the inside of the house (there is already a temp toilet on small "room" outside) and finally connect the soil pipes to the sewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any "temporary" installation of a toilet should be treated as a permanent one.  That means if you need to temporarily build up the floor, the temp floor needs to be securely anchored to the sub-floor and the toilet securely anchored to that temp floor.

If you do not install the toilet as if it were permanent you risk the release of raw sewage onto your new construction materials.

Brick and mortar, as Chris said, seems overkill.  Secure some wood to build up the floor to the proper level and secure the toilet to the flange as well as the flange to the pipe.

This *may* result in you having to redo some plumbing around the toilet, if, for instance, you find you need to remove the flange to install the floor, although generally you'll cut the floor around the flange.

Comment: In Brazil toilet installation doesn't use a flange. It is a 100mm pipe (4in) which ends at most 1 cm (3/8 in) above the floor. Then a gasket is place on the pipe and the toilet is place over it sealing the gasket. My main worry was to cut the pipe too short and then have to break the slab to replace the pipe.

Comment: Interesting.  How do you secure the toilet to the floor then?  Location info would also be helpful, I suppose...

Comment: There are holes on each side of the toilet and long screws are driven into the concrete floor below using anchors. Like [those](http://img2.mlstatic.com/parafuso-vaso-sanitario-bucha-10mm_MLB-O-4819635961_082013.jpg).

Comment: Ok then, minus the flange remark the above still stands.  You want the "temporary" base to be secure and the toilet also secure.